# Linux Shell Script: extract values from string in specified manner

Tags: linux, shell

I have one variable contain values like:

```
USER1:USER2,USER3:USER4,USER5:USER6
```

I want to extract values like `USER1,USER3,USER5`

For Example:

```
VALUE = USER1:USER2,USER3:USER4,USER5:USER6
```

how I `echo` to extract like this

```
USER1,USER3,USER5
```

Comment: Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Also please add tags, You don't even specify the language you are using.

Comment: What did you even try? How you failed?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

string=USER1:USER2,USER3:USER4,USER5:USER6
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$string"
output=

for kv in ${array[@]}; do
    key=$(echo $kv | cut -d':' -f1)
    output="$output,$key"
done

output=$(echo $output | cut -c 2-)
echo $output
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always consider adding an explanation to it.